# What is the difference between "will" and "would"?

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would, confusable

> “This system **Would** largely benefit the numerous migrant beneficiaries such as labourers, daily wagers, blue-collar workers etc. who frequently change their place of dwelling in search of employment or for other reasons across the country,” he said.

I have taken this from a newspaper. Can I use will instead of would here? If so, what is the difference in their meaning?

Answer (score 1):

"**This system will...**" tells us that the system is now working. (It is in place, or implemented.)

"**This system would...**" implies "IF this system were to be introduced, adopted or implemented it would..." Or perhaps, "IF we could get it to work, this system would..."

In other words, there is an implied [conditional](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if).