# Difference between more context will help and more context would help

Tags: difference, will-would

B answers a question from A. Speaker B uses "would", if I use "will", what is the difference?

> A: Could you please put in plain words the meaning of "unsatisfied" here, in the whole context (perhaps giving some close synonyms)?:
>
> *One by one they rolled away, filled with full but very unsatisfied hobbits.*
>
> B: More context **would** help!
>
> Satisfied can imply having had your fill of food – having eaten quite enough (“an ample sufficiency”, as is sometimes said). Here, the point seems to be that they have had enough of something (food?) but still don’t feel satisfied (contented?).

Comment: There are many questions here about the difference between _will_ and _would_, such as [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/231534/what-is-the-difference-between-will-and-would?rq=1). Basically, you use _will_ if the other person is definitely going to provide more context.

Comment: In practice, native speakers almost always use ***would*** in the cited context, but it wouldn't make any difference if they used ***will***. In this *specific context* it's vanishingly unlikely someone would explicitly choose ***will*** because they actually ***know*** (or wish to imply) that further context ***will*** be forthcoming, which ***will*** help. We just use *X **would** help* as "shorthand" for ***IF X** [happened / existed / was true], that would help*. For the "prediction" sense, *There will be more context, which will help*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your explanation is very clear. So "would" is used for something that doesn't exist, isn't it? Could you give an example sentence using "will" as further context **will** be fortcoming?

Comment: *"**Jane** has just asked a question, but she doesn't know all the details we need in order to answer it properly, so let's put that one "on hold" for now. Further details **will** be forthcoming when **John** arrives"*. Or ***John will** give us more context when he arrives*. We wouldn't use ***would*** there unless we also changed ***when*** to ***if***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["will" vs. "would"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/334324/will-vs-would)

Comment: How does your question here differ from [this one you posted 5 days ago](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343986/what-is-meant-by-direct-and-indirect)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers But if we turned it into conditional sentences, it would be the same. For instance: *it **will** help if you **give** more context* and *it **would** help if you **gave** more context.* I think there is no difference. Am I right? And if we simply say "more context will help", it doens't work. "More context would help" makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The *grammatical* difference is that "would" uses the *irrealis mood* and "will" does not.

The *semantic* difference is that "would" is an indirect indication of a problem, and a clear, polite suggestion that the listener do something. On the other hand, "will" is a direct indication of a problem, and only maybe a weak and blunt order for the listener to do something.

So if B had used "will" there rather than "would", it would come off either as a mere indication of a problem that anyone could solve, like, "*We should find more context*", or a passive-aggressive command, like, "*Get me more context!*"

Answer (score 0):

"Would" expresses a condition. If someone provided more context, then more clarity results.

"Will" expresses a future event. In this case, when someone proved more context, then more clarity results.

In this example, the two mean the same thing. More context results in clarity.

In some cases there could be a difference between a condition and a certainty. Like, "If I could afford a car, then I would get there more quickly." Versus, "When I buy a car, then I will get there more quickly." The first example is a possibility; the second is a certainty. But in real life, few things are absolute certainties, so we're really talking about a range of probabilities. Though I suppose some things are so close to certainty that we consider them 100%. Like it would be silly to say, "If the sun rises tomorrow morning, then I would ..."

Comment: In the sentence above, using "will" wouldn't make sense, doesn't it? "More context will help"

Answer (score -1):

Usage has [changed significantly](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%20will%20help%20if%2CIt%20would%20help%20if&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=20) over the past century...

[image]

Obviously it's inconceivable that the real-world contexts in which people might use either of these forms have changed so significantly. I take the chart as conclusive proof that *for almost all contexts, the two verb forms are equivalent*.

It's hardly worth trying to identify contexts where they're *not* interchangeable, because they arise so rarely.

Comment: So which should we use, "it will help if you give more context" or "it would help if you gave more context?" To me, because this is a real situation, I would use "it will help if you give more context." What do you think I'm right?

Comment: Many of the relatively few remaining uses of ***will*** in my chart will actually be "requoting" earlier uses, so the shift is even more extreme than you might think at first glance. Do like everyone else, and stick with ***would***. It's a complete waste of time you trying to understand a semantic difference that almost never exists anyway.

Comment: ...instead of (1) *I **would** use "It **will** help if you **give** more context"* you should be saying (2) *I **will** use "It **would** help if you **gave** more context."* Note that it's not particularly important to "backshift" ***give*** to ***gave*** in (2), because it's perfectly possible to parse it as *...if you [**would**] give more context* (with ***would*** "elided / deleted" because it's a predictable repetition of ***would*** before ***help***).

Comment: I have learnt type 1 conditional and type 2 conditional and the structure of the type 2 conditional can be used to make suggestions. *It **would** help if you **gave** more context* is right in this context. Is it also correct to say "*it **will** help if you **give** more context* in this case?

Comment: I think numbered conditionals are not a useful concept when learning English. There are *far* more types of conditional statements than have ever been assigned numbers, and the ones that actually *are* numbered and defined are inconsistent and overlap. Most native speakers know nothing about them, yet they speak English perfectly well. Your commitment to "learning" numbered conditionals  is probably what's preventing you from understanding the simple point which I've now made three times (once in the Answer, and twice in comments). Forget *It **will** help if...* (It's ***not*** helping! :)

Comment: The chart does not prove they are equivalent in meaning. It shows that preference for one has declined while preference for the other has risen. This correlation *suggests* they may be applicable in the same contexts. That's the most you can say about that chart.

Comment: @gotube: We must agree to disagree. I think it's ridiculous to suppose the real-world interactions between typical Anglophones can have changed so dramatically as to completely reverse idiomatic preference. Social interactions / behaviour / circumstances don't change that much that fast, but *language* certainly does!

Comment: @FumbleFingers The preference for being more or less polite could change within the culture, and that would lead to people using more/less polite phraseology, which is what I think has happened here. The two verb forms are not equivalent. See my answer for more details on how.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, if I substituted "would" for "will" in the sentence above, it wouldn't make sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Nyambek: We're talking about *idiomatic* usages here, so "wouldn't make sense" isn't really relevant (but note that your "tag question" in above comment should *reverse* the previous assertion: *"It wouldn't make sense, **would it**?"*). To be honest, I think you could just as well say B's *"More context would help!"* in the actual Question doesn't really make much sense on its own, because there's no explicit "condition" to justify "conditional" ***would***. The implied sense is *More context would help **if more context existed** (but it **doesn't!**)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks a lot for the correction. I really get it now. What I would like to know is why "will" doesn't make sense here? A native speaker always uses "would" (more context would help) and not "more context will help". It's difficult for me to dertemine whether I should use "will" or "would" in such a sentence. Does "will" refer to the future? The word "future" means "going to happen", doesn't it?

Comment: I seem to be saying the same thing again and again. The usage under consideration concerns ***established idioms*** - you *can't* "understand" it at the logical or literal level (even native Anglophones can't). Mostly you just need to commit to memory the fact that we use ***would*** in many contexts with no obvious justification *because it's evocative of politeness and deference*. Or more accurately, perhaps, *because that's what everyone else does*.